# Facing connection reset by peer, errorContext[NAMESPACE: <Namespace>] while sending messages to Azure queue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, amqp, azure-sdk

I am trying to send a message to a queue on the Azure service bus with ClientSecretCredential.it is giving error while using AzureSDK code. The code and error trace are given below. The latest jars are used and no compilation errors in the code.
When tried to send message on HTTPS , it works absolutely fine.

```
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusClientBuilder;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusMessage;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusSenderClient;


public class App {

    /* variables removed for confidentiality*/
    
    public void sendMessage() throws InterruptedException,Exception{

        ServiceBusMessage guestCheckInEvent = new ServiceBusMessage(data);
       
     
        guestCheckInEvent.setContentType(contentType);
        guestCheckInEvent.setMessageId(messageId);
        System.setProperty("AZURE_CLIENT_ID", clientId);
        System.setProperty("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET", clientSecret);
        System.setProperty("AZURE_TENANT_ID", tenantId);
     
        ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(clientId)
            .tenantId(tenantId)
            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
            .build();
        
            ServiceBusSenderClient sender = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
            .fullyQualifiedNamespace(nameSpace)
            .credential(credential)
            .sender()
            .queueName(queueName)
            .buildClient();      
                
        System.out.println("Sending message");
        sender.sendMessage(guestCheckInEvent);
        System.out.println("Sent message");
        sender.close();
    }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        App a=new App();
        try {
            a.sendMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            

        
    }
    }
```

## Error

```
com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusException: Retries exhausted: 3/3
        at com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusSenderAsyncClient.mapError(ServiceBusSenderAsyncClient.java:823)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$28(Mono.java:3773)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:180)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:225)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:274)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onError(FluxContextWrite.java:121)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.maybeOnError(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:326)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:211)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.drain(SinkManyEmitterProcessor.java:471)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(SinkManyEmitterProcessor.java:269)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:100)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:190)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.onError(FluxTimeout.java:219)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:234)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:241)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:315)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:180)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:142)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:180)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:142)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxHide.java:142)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onError(MonoIgnoreThen.java:278)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.onError(FluxTimeout.java:219)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxFilterFuseable.java:162)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$SizeBoundReplayBuffer.replayNormal(FluxReplay.java:865)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$SizeBoundReplayBuffer.replay(FluxReplay.java:965)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$ReplaySubscriber.onError(FluxReplay.java:1360)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onError(MonoIgnoreThen.java:278)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:231)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkEmptyMulticast$VoidInner.complete(SinkEmptyMulticast.java:272)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkEmptyMulticast.tryEmitEmpty(SinkEmptyMulticast.java:86)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkEmptySerialized.tryEmitEmpty(SinkEmptySerialized.java:46)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalEmptySink.emitEmpty(InternalEmptySink.java:26)
        at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorConnection.lambda$closeConnectionWork$35(ReactorConnection.java:540)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRunnable.call(MonoRunnable.java:73)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRunnable.call(MonoRunnable.java:32)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:228)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkEmptyMulticast$VoidInner.complete(SinkEmptyMulticast.java:272)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkEmptyMulticast.tryEmitEmpty(SinkEmptyMulticast.java:86)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkEmptySerialized.tryEmitEmpty(SinkEmptySerialized.java:46)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalEmptySink.emitEmpty(InternalEmptySink.java:26)
        at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorExecutor.close(ReactorExecutor.java:188)
        at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorExecutor.lambda$scheduleCompletePendingTasks$1(ReactorExecutor.java:173)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
        Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
                at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:139)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1734)
                at com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusSenderClient.sendMessage(ServiceBusSenderClient.java:192)
                at App.sendMessage(App.java:44)
                at App.main(App.java:52)
Caused by: reactor.core.Exceptions$RetryExhaustedException: Retries exhausted: 3/3
        at reactor.core.Exceptions.retryExhausted(Exceptions.java:306)
        at reactor.util.retry.RetryBackoffSpec.lambda$static$0(RetryBackoffSpec.java:68)
        at reactor.util.retry.RetryBackoffSpec.lambda$null$4(RetryBackoffSpec.java:560)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:183)
        ... 55 more
Caused by: com.azure.core.amqp.exception.AmqpException: Connection reset by peer, errorContext[NAMESPACE: <Namespace>. ERROR CONTEXT: N/A]
        at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ExceptionUtil.toException(ExceptionUtil.java:85)
        at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ConnectionHandler.notifyErrorContext(ConnectionHandler.java:351)
        at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ConnectionHandler.onTransportError(ConnectionHandler.java:253)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:191)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:324)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:291)
        at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorExecutor.run(ReactorExecutor.java:91)
        ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0):

> Send a message to a queue on the Azure service bus with ClientSecretCredential.

The error maybe that you don't have the proper role or permission to send the message. you need to assign **`Azure service bus Data Owner`** to your Application like below:

**Portal:**
[image]

After assigning the role to the application. I tried with the below code and it sends a message to the queue using Azure Java SDK.

**Code:**

```
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusClientBuilder;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusMessage;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusSenderClient;


public final class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        String data="Hi how are you?";
        String contentType="text/plain";
        String messageId="6";
        String queueName="test1";
        String clientId="xxx";
        String tenantId="xxxxx";
        String clientSecret="xxxxxx";

        ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(clientId)
            .tenantId(tenantId)
            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
            .build();

    ServiceBusSenderClient senderClient = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
            .fullyQualifiedNamespace("venkat678.servicebus.windows.net")
            .credential(credential)
            .sender()
            .queueName(queueName)
            .buildClient();
        ServiceBusMessage guestCheckInEvent = new ServiceBusMessage(data);
        guestCheckInEvent.setContentType(contentType);
        guestCheckInEvent.setMessageId(messageId);
    // send one message to the queue
    senderClient.sendMessage(guestCheckInEvent);
    System.out.println("Sent a single message to the queue with properties: " + queueName);
        }
```

**Output:**

```
Sent a single message to the queue with properties: test1
```

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**

[Get started with Azure Service Bus queues (Java) - Azure Service Bus | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues?tabs=passwordless)

Comment: We have the Azure Service Data Bus Sender and Azure Service Data Bus Receiver roles set already. Hence, we were able to send message to Service Bus through HTTPS. The issue is when sending through Azure SDK

Comment: Hi @user3725074 Have you tried my approach?

Comment: Hi Venkatesan, Do you mean with the Azure service bus Data Owner role?

Comment: Yes, You need to assign azure service data owner role to your application.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have permissions to set the Azure service bus Data Owner role. Hence, I cannot tell if that solution works.